# Urgency of 2003 Isuzu Rodeo suspension groaning?

Tags: noise, suspension

It's making a pretty obvious creaky-bed noise.  However, I am currently on a road trip, and getting serviced would be somewhat onerous.  I am wondering what the failure modes of the suspension system in this particular vehicle are?  Might the car fully drop onto the tires?  Or will it all just seize up and subject me to a bumpier-than usual ride?  What is the urgency of getting my clearly worn suspension serviced?

Comment: You should have someone capable take a look. Groaning may only be a dry/perished rubber donut, or it may herald something more serious. There's no way to answer your query without examining the suspension in person. Maybe it doesn't need to be worked on right now...but maybe it does.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica this answers my question.